# Where is TypeScript File Template?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2015

I have an existing web project in angular 2 and asp.net core. I am trying to add a typescript file to a folder using add new item but there is no typescript file template under visual c#.

I am using Visual Studio 2015 and I have web essentials installed.

Do I have to add some sort of package to the project?

In Tools->Extensions and Updates I have this "TypeScript For Microsoft Visual Studio" But then why doesn't it have any effect.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you have trouble finding a template, use the Search box (usually in the top right of the "Add New Item" dialog.

[image]

The chances are you'll find the TypeScript template straight away. In older releases of Visual Studio you needed the TypeScript extension.

Comment: I dont have that typescript file which u are getting. Also typing in search box does not give that to me